# jQuery selector for next div by class in a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, append

I have tried many things but none seem to work.

What I am trying to do is create a database that will store serial numbers for all the stock I receive, I can get the basic functions to work.

Within the HTML I have a Javascript function that adds extra serial number fields according to the qty input.

My only problem is that when I add another product field to the table and change its qty field, it adds the extra fields to all of the serial number cells.

All I need is help with finding the right selector for the next div with the class ".serials".

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AvKRW/10/

```
$(".serials").append("<input type='text' name='serial[]' id='serial-number' /><br />");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are finding all elements with the specified class and appending to all of them.

Are you looking for:

```
 $(".serials").last ()
```

Alternatively you could use

```
 $(".serials").eq (INDEX)
```

The latter should enable you to append to only one of the serial boxes based on index.

It appears that parsing the dom tree of html elements would allow you to filter your selection of html elements to just the few you require. please see changes I have made to your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AvKRW/7/

Comment: That is kinda what I need although the HTML in my document is dynamic so, unless the `$(".serials").eq (INDEX)` function works relative to the position where the change is happening, it will not work in my case. EDIT: I just tested it, doesn't seem to work, unless there is something else i am missing

Comment: If you have access to the current serial field you could use .next () to iterate. Alternatively I think it may be easier for you to use parent () function on the quantity field to move up a level to your td then .next () to find the parent of your serial box at which point you could use $('.serials') to access a singular serial field.

Comment: Is it not possible to use the unique id of your quantity field also as a class on the relevant serial fields? You could then select the appropriate serials related to that quantity box?

Comment: A unique id for each of the serial field sets would be ideal, but as my HTML is create dynamically, i would then need javascript code to identify which qty box is being changed and then to determine which serial number div to append to.

Comment: Your first comment makes complete sense, although i cannot seem to get the code to work, as i am still new to jQuery my syntax may be wrong, at the moment i have `$parent().next($(".serials").append("<input type='text' name='serial[]' id='serial-number' /><br />"))`

Comment: I've added a fiddle to my answer. You will also need to add the change event to your additional Qty fields.

Comment: I have the change event to happen when an element with the class .qty-input is changed but i guess the .change function will only work with the first of the class? as it does not seem to work with the other inputs

Comment: This is because you assign the event handler at the beginning when you only have one input. You can assign to multiple using a selector but the elements have to exist.

Comment: Done! Finally, I added the function that changes the qty fields to the end of the function that adds the extra products. Thus making sure the new qty-input has the function.
jsFiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/AvKRW/10/`